# how to set a simple css `:hover {` color changing upon an `svg` used in `background:url()`

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to set a simple css `:hover {` color changing upon an `svg` used in `background:url()`

I'm trying to use `stroke="currentColor"`, but this is not working.

The only possible way seems to be to duplicate the code by just changing the color, but obviously that's not the most elegant solution.

Did I miss something ?

this is my code:

```css
.sz30 {
  --siz   : 30px;
  display : inline-block;
  width   : var(--siz);
  height  : var(--siz);
  margin  : 1rem;
  background-size : cover;
  cursor          : pointer;
  caret-color     : transparent;
  }

.test_ccGreen {
  color:green;
  background : url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="3" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M4.34 2.93l12.73 12.73-1.41 1.41L2.93 4.35z"/><path d="M17.07 4.34L4.34 17.07l-1.41-1.41L15.66 2.93z"/></svg>');
  }
.test_ccBlue {  
  color:blue;
  background : url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="3"  ><defs>%3Cstyle%3Epath{stroke:currentColor;}%3C/style%3E</defs><path d="M4.34 2.93l12.73 12.73-1.41 1.41L2.93 4.35z"/><path d="M17.07 4.34L4.34 17.07l-1.41-1.41L15.66 2.93z"/></svg>');
}
.test_ccGreen:hover, .test_ccBlue:hover { color:red; } 

.test_duplicateSVG {
  background : url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(24,97,52)"><path d="M4.34 2.93l12.73 12.73-1.41 1.41L2.93 4.35z"/><path d="M17.07 4.34L4.34 17.07l-1.41-1.41L15.66 2.93z"/></svg>');
}

.test_duplicateSVG:hover {
  background : url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="3" stroke="crimson"><path d="M4.34 2.93l12.73 12.73-1.41 1.41L2.93 4.35z"/><path d="M17.07 4.34L4.34 17.07l-1.41-1.41L15.66 2.93z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div class="sz30 test_ccGreen"></div>
<div class="sz30 test_ccBlue"></div>

<div class="sz30 test_duplicateSVG"></div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at this article: https://css-tricks.com/change-color-of-svg-on-hover/#aa-svg-background-images

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you very much!, I will look into this, it seems that using a mask would be my preference

Answer (score 1):

First of all, background-image:url svg***
its not svg. its rendering like image.
so you cant use svg props there. its just image.
you would use filter method.

if you wanna use like svg. just paste svg codes in to html, then write css.

its 2 example for you:

```css
.sz30 {
  --siz: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--siz);
  height: var(--siz);
  margin: 1rem;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  caret-color: transparent;
}

.test_ccGreen {
  color: green;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="3" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M4.34 2.93l12.73 12.73-1.41 1.41L2.93 4.35z"/><path d="M17.07 4.34L4.34 17.07l-1.41-1.41L15.66 2.93z"/></svg>');
}

.sz30:hover {
  filter: invert(73%) sepia(14%) saturate(666%) hue-rotate(301deg) brightness(108%) contrast(101%);
}


/* 
filter generator:
https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp
*/


/* css*/

.real-svg svg {
  stroke: pink;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.real-svg svg:hover {
  stroke: black;
}


/* and for images*/
```

```html
<!--oldies-->
<div class="sz30 test_ccGreen"></div>

<!--goldies-->
<div class="real-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke-width="3" stroke="crimson"><path d="M4.34 2.93l12.73 12.73-1.41 1.41L2.93 4.35z"/><path d="M17.07 4.34L4.34 17.07l-1.41-1.41L15.66 2.93z"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It's nice of you to answer me but sorry, I should have indicated that I already know all of this, but that I am looking for something more "simple". see my answers here, use of [svg symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377733/underlined-text-should-have-prolonged-underline-for-its-image-on-hover/77378053#77378053), [svg filter calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters/56723735#56723735) (which deserves to be better known)

Answer (score 0):

I presume your are stuffing SVG in `background` because you want to prevent style-bleeding, duplicate ID issues, etc. And maybe even SSG.

I also presume (since you are drawing icons) you are creating UI icons, and not huge SVGs

It might be easier then to define a ***native* Web Component** `<svg-icon>`
that creates all SVG *client-side*;

With shadowDOM so you get the same encapsulation as an IMG background, but the ability to style it with global CSS (because *inheritable* styles like `color` do cascade into shadowDOM)

Note: (unlike Frameworks) it doesn't matter *when* you *define* the Web Component; all existing or future `<svg-icon>` elements will automagically be upgraded.
You can put this code in a `<script>` in the `<head>` to prevent FOUCs

```html
<style>
  svg-icon {
    color: grey;
    --iconhovercolor:green;
    width: 120px;
  }
</style>

<svg-icon></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="plus" style="color:hotpink"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="plus" style="color:blue"></svg-icon>

<script>
  customElements.define('svg-icon', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      Object.assign(this.style, { display: "inline-block", cursor: "pointer" });
      let is    = this.getAttribute("is")    || "plus";
      let color = this.getAttribute("color") || "currentcolor";
      let d = {
        "plus": "m40 80 40 0 0-40 40 0 0 40 40 0 0 40-40 0 0 40-40 0 0-40-40 0z",
        "save": "ADD YOUR OWN ICONS HERE"
      }[ is ];
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
          .innerHTML = `<style>
                          path{fill:${color}}
                          svg{vertical-align:top}
                          svg:hover{color:var(--iconhovercolor,red)}
                        </style>
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
                          <path d="${d}" stroke="${color}"/>
                        </svg>`;
      this.onclick = (evt) => {
           console.log("You clicked me!", is);
      }
      this.onmouseover = (evt) => {
        //
      }
    }});
</script>
```

##### `<load-file>` for larger, external SVG (loaded into shadowDOM)

If you do have large SVGs, and can keep them external,
you can use the [<load-file> Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about

##### Or for SSG

You can use a declarative shadowDOM (without using any JavaScript)

(jan 2024) Almost supported in all Browsers... we are waiting for FireFox.. [looks like it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1712140) will be available in the next FireFox release

```html
<svg-plus>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      path     { fill:currentcolor }
      svg      { vertical-align:top; width:120px }
      svg:hover{ color:green }
    </style>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <path d="m40 80 40 0 0-40 40 0 0 40 40 0 0 40-40 0 0 40-40 0 0-40-40 0z"/>
    </svg>  
  </template>
</svg-plus>

<svg-min>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      path     { fill:currentcolor }
      svg      { vertical-align:top; width:120px }
      svg:hover{ color:green }
    </style>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <path d="M80 80l40 0 40 0 0 40-40 0-80 0 0-40z"/>
    </svg>  
  </template>
</svg-min>
```

Comment: This one applies the same ``viewBox`` to all, you can just wrap a complete ``<svg>`` for every icon in a Web Component to keep it simple

Comment: I have been stuffing my knowledge into a GPT today. [This First draft](https://chat.openai.com/g/g-quK0nMtwZ-create-or-refactor-your-web-component) will help creating or refactoring Web Components

Comment: Nowadays questions hardly get upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg

Comment: Please do not change the order of my code examples; I use the same order in (most) my replies and on public blogs for a reason... **Show -> Do**, instead of first trying to push a concept with just code (most do not understand)

Comment: No worries, I want my code to be easy to read for people who haven't see Web Component code before (and that is most of this worlds population) That is why I always start code with the Web Component used HTML first

Comment: ultimately this answer does not suit me, it generates and uses way too much code. as indicated in my question, I am looking for a solution mainly focused on css